# How get props location in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

How get location from props?

```
function TobaccoLine({ match, props  }) {
   const activeTab = useSelector(state => props.location.state ? props.location.state.activeTab : 0);
...
}
```

Props are undefined.

ReactJS v16.13.1

Comment: why are you not doing
`function TobaccoLine(props )`

Comment: I don't know difference

Comment: check on spreading, `(props)` means you are trying to receive props from the component as an object while `({props})` means from the props object the component is receiving you want the prop value in the prop object i.e `prop.prop` which is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the location instead of props.

```
function TobaccoLine({ match, location }) {
   const activeTab = useSelector(state => location.state ? location.state.activeTab : 0);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are deconstructing the props, so you need to do:

```
function TobaccoLine(props) {
   const { match } = props;
   const activeTab = useSelector(state => props.location.state ? props.location.state.activeTab : 0);
...
}
```

When you deconstruct, i.e. `{ match, props}`, you are actually looking for `props.props` and `props.match`, if that makes sense.